# How to maximize FXML loaded inside a scene?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to have a setup with one `MenuBar` and a `Pane` container below it to load different FXMLs depending on the clicked `MenuItem`; these two are currently inside a `VBox`.

The stage (window) is maximized alright using `stage.setMaximized(true)`. The `MenuBar` spans the entire width of the window fine. Even when window is resized.

However, although I can switch FXMLs on the container with no problem, the result is not taking up the remaining space. I wanted to give it an effect like `DockStyle.Fill` in WinForms. How to get around this? Do I need to use another container other than `Pane`?

Comment: `Pane` is a primitive layout that only sizes its children to their preferred size.

Comment: @Slaw Is there another layout that'll do the trick?

Comment: A [`StackPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) might work for you.

Comment: `VBox` should work. I am guessing you are not setting some property correctly.